# Lambda expression to match a List<string>

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have a list

```
List<String> versionList = new List<String> {"version1", "version2", "version3"}
```

I want to match my megaList with each item in List versionList, if any of the item in versionList matches the item in megalist then it would perform some action.

What lambda expression should I use to accomplish it?

**Edit** Edited to give specific requirements

```
foreach (var m in MegaList)        
    .Where(m => m.list.Version.ToLower().Contains(
                           <What should I put here to match this m.list.Version 
                           to match each item in versionList>)) ) //confused here
{
// do some action
}
```

My question is different from the question marked as duplicate as I want to match a particular item in megalist if it contains any of the item from versionList, apologies if I have confused the question.

Also as per the answer in duplicate question and the answers below

How can I accomplish this

```
foreach (var m in MegaList)  
.Where(v => versionList.Contains(m => m.list.Version))
```

when I do the above m is not accessible in this command, this is where I am stuck as I have to match the version of list in each item in Megalist.

**Simple Explanation of requirement**

To explain this in simple terms, MegaList is a list of programs running, I am checking this list of running programs by matching it to the versionList, if the running program matches the versionList then only the code should be executed, hence I want to match the version of list of Megalist with the versionList,

Comment: Can you please point me to that particular question that matches my question, because I asked this question when I was not able to find an answer, thanks :)

Comment: Oops, I just saw that the link to question marked as duplicate is on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This basically gets every record in the `MegaList` which is also contained within the `versionList`. In this case `x` is an value in your `MegaList`, therefore we do a simple `List<>.Contains()` on the `versionList` with the `x` value.

```
foreach (var m in MegaList.Where(x => versionList.Contains(x.ToLower()))) 
{
// do some action
}
```

Comment: @user3677174 Haha actually I wasn't talking to you I was talking to XN16.

Comment: @Kazark I have now added a bit of an explanation. However your kind of comment should be applied to all answers to a question where applicable rather than singling out individual answers!

Comment: @XN16 Your answer came up in a review queue. I did not see any other answers.

Comment: @Kazark Fair enough, I assume it was flagged due to the similarity to another answer for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @XN16, my query is not fully satisfied, but your answer is perfect for the question I asked. What I want is that the if part of item in megaList matches versionList then it should work, but in this it won't, any suggestions. for e.g. if megaList item is "Bank soft version1", then this won't work

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
foreach (var m in MegaList.Where(i => versionList.Contains(i.ToLower())) 
{
// do some action
}
```